# IIS/ASP.NET Security Settings

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-8.5

I have a Windows Server that is a member server of an AD domain.

On it there is an IIS web site with Physical Path set to `D:\www`.

The site's Application Pool is set to a .NET CLR Version v4.0.30319 one with Integrated pipeline mode and running under the identity `LocalService`.

Under the web site's IIS Authentication, I have Windows Authentication set to Enabled.

I want to allow all authenticated users, either domain or with local server credentials, to access the web site. What are the security settings I must have for the `D:\www` folder?

Right now, `SYSTEM` and `Users` & `IIS_IUSRS` has Read, Read & Execute and List folder contents permissions. And all authenticated users appear to be able to access the web site without problems.

But when I remove `IIS_IUSRS` from the ACL, no user can access because web.config couldn't be read. Why is this the case? Where in the web site configuration is `IIS_IUSRS` specified? And anyway, my `IIS_IUSRS` currently has no members.

Comment: `when I remove IIS_IUSRS from the ACL, no user can access because web.config couldn't be read. Why is this the case?` It's the identity of the web site application pool.

Comment: But that is `LocalService`.

Comment: `D:\www` should follow `\inetpub\wwwroot` https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/981949/description-of-default-permissions-and-user-rights-for-iis-7-0-and-lat What happened after removing `IIS_IUSRS` is by design and you have to add it back. BTW, `LocalService` should not be used as pool identity as well (unless you have strong justification).

Comment: `LocalService` was a requirement by security policy of the customer who owned the server. I am puzzled because the `IIS_IUSRS` group has no members.